# How to retrive product sku List using product id

Tags: laravel-5, bigcommerce

I want get Product sku List detail by using product Id & using filter by name.
Here is my code.

`$filter = array("name"=>$newSkuName);
$skusdList = $this->store->getProductSkus(930,$filter);
print_r($skusdList);`

And function getProductSkus is like below,

```
public static function getProductSkus($product_id,$filter = array())
{
    $filter = Filter::create($filter);
    return self::getCollection('/products/'.$product_id.'/skus'. $filter->toQuery(),'Sku');
}
```

Please tell me what is the problem?

Comment: I don't think you are including the BC PHP file correctly. Do:
`require 'path_to_bc/autoload.php';`
`use BigCommerce\Api\Client as bc`

Then in your function:
replace `self::` with `bc::`
`bc::getCollection`

Comment: You can print BC errors via: `print_r(bc::getLastError());`